# Is calculating a moving average a good way to approximate k-nearest neighbor regression?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, moving-average, nonparametric-regression

Given i.i.d samples (*x<sub>1</sub>*,*y<sub>1</sub>*), ... (*x<sub>n</sub>*,*y<sub>n</sub>*) such that *y<sub>i</sub>* = *f<sub>0</sub>*(*x<sub>i</sub>*) + *$\epsilon$<sub>i</sub>*, *i* = 1,... *n* for some *f<sub>0</sub>*

Suppose I want an estimate $\hat{f}$ of *f<sub>0</sub>* using *k*-nearest-neighbors regression in the neighborhood of each *x<sub>i</sub>* in my dataset. So for each *x<sub>i</sub>*, I must search for the *k* nearest neighboring elements and take the average of the set of all *y<sub>j</sub>* such that *j* $\in$ $\mathcal{N}$*<sub>k</sub>*(*x<sub>i</sub>*) where $\mathcal{N}$*<sub>k</sub>*(*x*) contains the *k* nearest points of *x*:

$$\hat{f}(x_i) = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j\in\mathcal{N}_k(x_i)} y_j$$

Now if my *x<sub>i</sub>* are all evenly spaced, then I could simply sort them in ascending order and calculate a moving average over corresponding elements in *y* with window size *k*. My question is: Will this moving average be approximately equivalent to *k*-nearest neighbors regression even if  (*x<sub>1</sub>*, ... *x<sub>n</sub>*) are not evenly spaced? Are there any tests I can do on the distribution ***P***(x) to check the quality of approximation?

Comment: *Moving average model* is a fixed notion which is quite different from *moving average* in general – see [this](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4953/confusing-moving-average-tag-split-into-two) and perhaps edit the title.

Comment: Is $x_i$ going to be the midpoint of the window?

Comment: Yes, sorry I left that detail out. $x_i$ will be the middle element/median of the window. Of course, if ($x_1$, ... $x_n$) are evenly spaced, then $x_i$ will also be the mean of the window.

Comment: Is the endgoal to gain some computation speed? Are there a lot of data points? I mean why do want to avoid the nearest neighbor?

Comment: Yes. There are 300,000 observations in my dataset so my question was partly motivated by the need to speed it up. However, I am curious to know if I can use moving average as a general strategy because the results looked very similar - at least in my one dataset.